# How to synchronize SVN revision and version ressources of EXE/DLL files?

Tags: c++, svn, resources, build-automation

Say I have some C++ project which builds an exe or dll file. The project is checked into a SVN repository. I want to automatically synchronize the revision from SVN with the version resource embedded in my exe/dll file, i.e. the version should be something like **$major.$minor.$svn_revision**.
Any ideas on how to achieve this? Are there any out-of-the-box solutions available?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have TortoiseSVN installed, then there is a program installed with it, `SubWCRev`.

If, in your file, you have this value:

```
$WCREV$
```

Then it'll be replaced with the highest committed revision number if you execute something like this:

```
SubWCRev .\ yourfile.txt.template yourfile.txt
```

This will copy from `yourfile.txt.template`, do the substitutions, and write to `yourfile.txt`.

Note that there's a lot of other macros you can use as well, if you execute `SubWCRev` without any arguments, it'll list them all on the console.

Comment: SubWCRev is also available separately for those who don't (want) to use TortoiseSVN: http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=138498&package_id=281312

Comment: well thats my fact for the day :)

Comment: ...and it looks as though the separately-available `SubWCRev` is statically compiled, so all you need is the exe file, and no need for a bunch of TortoiseSVN DLLs.

Comment: Hi, this doesn't work for resource files. Somehow it replaces $WCREV$ strings in a hand written .h file but not an .rc file. I created a version.template file which is a resource file including version information. I feed it to subwcrev to generate the actual .rc file but still $WCREV$ strings stay as is. Anyone got an idea ?

Comment: Anyways, I solved it. I include my custom .h file from the .rc file and everything works as expected.

Answer (score 4):

The answer by Program.X works great.  I'd like to add, though, that if you build your executable before committing your changes, the revision will be one less than the actual revision number of the running code.  To mitigate this, you can set the versions to

```
"2.0.$WCREV$.$WCMODS?1:0$"
```

That will put a 1 on the end if there are any local modifications, and 0 if not.  So if you look at your executable later and see 2.0.54.1, you know it's probably actually revision 55.

Comment: More info on the keywords available in WCREV is available here:  http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-subwcrev-keywords.html

Comment: Good point. I had noticed that, looks like a good workaround to flag this.

Comment: I like this, since you can see if the version is really a 1:1 build of the SVN content or a modified build.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look into [Subversion Properties](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.props.html) and [Subversion Keywords](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html). They don't solve the resource problem since they always include that damned `$KeywordName: ...$`
part. Custom properties do provide a nice method for making metadata available in batch files and what not.

Anyway, I looked for a solution to the resource problem a few years ago and didn't find one. So, we created our own home-grown solution. We changed our RC file to include a header file that was generated during the build process. The RC was dependent on the header and the header had a custom build rule that invoked a batch file to generate the header. The following snippet will extract the current revision from the output of `svn info`.

```
SET rootdir=%1
SET svnrev=0
PUSHD "%rootdir%"
FOR /F "tokens=1-4 delims=: " %%I IN ('svn info') DO (
    IF /I {%%I}=={rev} SET svnrev=%%L
)
(ECHO./*
 ECHO. * version-stamp.h - repository version information
 ECHO. */
 ECHO.#ifndef VERSION_STAMP_H
 ECHO.#define VERSION_STAMP_H
 ECHO.#define REPOSITORY_VERSION %svnrev%
 ECHO.#endif) > include\version-stamp.h
POPD
```

Then we created a component specific version stamping header named `component-info.h` that looked something like:

```
#ifndef component_info_h
#define component_info_h
#include "product-info.h"
#include "version-stamp.h"

#define VERS_MAJOR 1
#define VERS_MINOR 2
#define VERS_PATCH 3
#define VERS_BUILD REPOSITORY_VERSION

#define MY_COMPONENT_NAME "TPS Report Generator"    
#define MY_VERSION_NUMBER VERS_MAJOR,VERS_MINOR,VERS_PATCH,VERS_BUILD
#define MY_VERSION_STRING VERSION_STRING(VERS_MAJOR,VERS_MINOR,VERS_PATCH,VERS_BUILD)

#endif
```

Finally, we had a product-line version file that defined the product information named `product-info.h`:

```
#ifndef product_info_h
#define product_info_h

#define PROD_VERS_MAJOR 0
#define PROD_VERS_MINOR 1
#define PROD_VERS_PATCH 0
#define PROD_VERS_BUILD 0

#define VSTR1(s) #s
#define VSTR(s) VSTR1(s)
#define VERSION_STRING(a,b,c,d) VSTR(a) "." VSTR(b) "." VSTR(c) "." VSTR(d) "\0"

#define MY_COMPANY_NAME         "IniTech\0"
#define MY_COPYRIGHT            "Copyright ©2009 " MY_COMPANY_NAME
#define MY_PRODUCT_NAME         "\0"
#define MY_PRODUCT_VERSION_NUM  PROD_VERS_MAJOR,PROD_VERS_MINOR,PROD_VERS_PATCH,PROD_VERS_BUILD
#define MY_PRODUCT_VERSION_STR  VERSION_STRING(PROD_VERS_MAJOR,PROD_VERS_MINOR,PROD_VERS_PATCH,PROD_VERS_BUILD)
#endif
```

Then your resource file includes `component-info.h` and uses the various defines in the appropriate places (e.g., `FILEVERSION MY_VERSION_NUMBER`). This structure gave us a lot of flexibility and traceability in the whole version stamping process. It grew from a simple chunk in a batch file into this multi-leveled monstrosity but it has worked very well for us for the last few years.

I find it hard to believe that no one has found a better way to do this yet. Then again, I haven't investigated it for a number of years. I would assume that you could add a custom `.rules` file that defines a custom tool that handles this.

Answer (score 3):

This is great help, thanks. I've refined this for Visual Studio 2008 if it's of any help to anyone.

1/ Created a /Build folder within each project

2/ Copied AssemblyInfo.cs to the Build folder as AssemblyInfo.cs.txt, set the Build Action to "None"

3/ Edited the AssemblyInfo.cs.txt to have version attributes as below:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("2.0.0.$WCREV$")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("2.0.0.$WCREV$")]
```

4/ Added the following to the Prebuild events:

```
SubWCRev $(SolutionDir) $(ProjectDir)\Build\AssemblyInfo.cs.txt $(ProjectDir)\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs
```

This works everytime you compile.

I am using VisualSVN/TortoiseSVN and VisualSVN Server with Visual Studio 2008.

**UPDATE:**

My colleague has just updated his working copy and AssemblyInfo.cs is conflicted. Seems obvious. I have excluded it from SVN using VisualSVN to resolve this.